# Python2 Logger "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode" issue

Tags: python-2.7, python-unicode

I am writing in Python2 with `__future__` library imported.

When I want to log an unicode string as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("╔")
```

I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/gcc-5-glibc-2.23/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 876, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 231: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary ugly fix. But, why is that? And is there a better fix?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging
import sys
reload(sys)  # noqa
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("╔")
```